# How can I check mail from the command line?

Tags: command-line, email

I use Evolution to send and receive mail via IMAP. I want to keep using Evolution most of the time, but I want the option to check and read mail from the command line as well. Reading a new email from the command line should cause Evolution to also display it as read (so I don't have to read them twice), but simply fetching from CLI without marking as read should not make Evolution fail to fetch it.

How can I do this? I know there is a `mail` command, but that seems to display mail from my OS to my Linux user, not the mail sent from other people to my email box.

Comment: You could use [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), which could mark the messages as read on the mail server, and Evolution would view them as read once it syncs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it to be a bit complicated to set up CLI clients like mutt, neomutt, alpine.

Instead, I set up `offlineimap`. This only synchronizes mail to a local folder, but has no UI for actually reading or sending mail. It is still complicated, because mail server accounts are complicated, but at least you deal *only* with the account details in the config. It is also quite slow, and I have not found a solution yet beyond patience.

Once the mail is in a local folder, any client including mutt and GUI clients like Evolution can be used to read it. You can also use scripts and terminal programs to manipulate the mail - they are just text files.

Answer (score 11):

mutt is the right choice, try

```
mutt -f "imaps://USER:PASS@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
```

Press `?` to show keyboard commands.

Comment: My provider is not Gmail. Also this results in my email pass being in the shell history in plaintext.

Comment: Sure, and your name is not USER and your password is not PASS. The generic syntax without password is ``mutt -f imaps://USER@imap.notgmail.com/INBOX``.

Comment: @Bagalaw Simply add a space before typing in the command. It will prevent the command from being logged.